# Windows 10 crashing when connecting to Internet

Tags: windows-10-preview, wifi-driver

I just successfully installed a Windows 10 preview (build 10130) alongside Linux Mint on an old xp machine. I also installed the drivers for my netgear WLAN1100 adapter so I could connect to the internet. The driver install went ok, but when I try to connect, the computer crashes, and gives the following error:


IRQL_UNEXPECTED_VALUE


I followed instructions online to reinstall the drivers in Windows 7 compatibility mode and as administrator. But it still crashes. Any ideas?


Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a driver conflict, report it, the uninstall the driver and try the generic driver if available

Comment: What do you mean by the 'generic driver'? I don't have as much experience with Windows as with Linux. :)

Comment: Oddly try a different slot for the card.  Like stated, windows had wlan autoconfiguration stuff built in, and it can be preferable to make the connect with that, although you may still need the base driver for the card device, you can avoid the software.

Comment: @PDF - Most devices work with a device driver delivered through Windows update.  I am going to guess the lan driver is buggy and simply will not work with Windows 10.  Netgear doesn't support their devices on beta operating systems.